# ¿Cómo deserializar un json que es de una clase entre una lista de clases?

Tags: c#, json, parsear

Os cuento mi situación, tengo un archivo json el cual obtengo tal que :

```
string jsonData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
```

En este caso, como ejemplo, un json puede ser tal que :

```
[
  {
  "nombre": "Ivan"
  },
  {
  "nombre": "Francisco"
  }
]
```

o

```
[{
  "edad": 55
}]
```

o

```
[
  {
  "dimensiones": 2500
 },{
  "dimensiones": 800
 },{
  "dimensiones": 500
 },
]
```

o

```
[
{
  "esNueva": false
}
]
```

El problema es que tengo que deserializarlo pero no sé a qué clase va a pertencer.
Como en el ejemplo supongamos que tengo estas 4 clases:

```
public class Persona
{
   string nombre{ get; set; }
}

public class Animal
{
   int edad{ get; set; }
}

public class Ropa
{
   bool esNueva { get; set; }
}

public class Foto
{
   int dimensiones { get; set; }
}
```

La idea es que el json es una de esas clases pero no sé cual exactamente. He pensado en hacer una clase que resuelva el string que corresponde al json, pero no sé como hacer un método que pueda devolver un objeto que conozco pero no sé seguro cual es.

¿Comó podría hacer este método?

Comment: cómo es tu json?

Comment: He editado la pregunta para responderte

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sino conoces a cual clase perteneder el json podrias realizar la prueba controlando el error

[Serialization Error Handling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm)

entonces la deserializacion seria por prueba y error, vas deserializando a cada una de las clases y ves cual no falla, entonces conoces que se trata de esa estructura la coincidente

```
string jsonData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Error = delegate(object sender, ErrorEventArgs args)
    {
      args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
    }
});

var persona = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Persona>(jsonData, settings);

if(persona != null)
{
    //si distinto de null entonces pudo deserializar
}

var animal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Animal>(jsonData, settings);

if(animal != null)
{
    //si distinto de null entonces pudo deserializar
}

//igual al resto
```

vas intentando con cada clase y validas cual pudo deserializar.

Mientras tengas un `null` como respesta es que falla y no pudo deserializar, la setting indica que no lance el exception asi no tienes que trabajar con el `try...catch` y puedes validarlo con el `if`